# Custom storage system in Django

Tags: django

I'm trying to write a simple custom storage system.

I need only that my storage system duplicate files from a few FTP servers.

Subclass of storage looks like:

```
from django.core.files.storage import Storage
from settings import MEDIA_ROOT, MEDIA_URL
import ftplib
import os



class FTPStorage(Storage):
    """FTP Storage class for Django pluggable storage system."""

    def __init__(self, mediaroot=MEDIA_ROOT, base_url=MEDIA_URL):
        self._netrc=open('netrc')
        self._machine=[]
        self._login=[]
        self._password=[]


 def _save(self, name, content):
     content.open()
        if hasattr(content, 'chunks'):
            content_str = ''.join(chunk for chunk in content.chunks())
        else:
            content_str = content.read() 
        for line in netrc: #read netrc file
            old=line.strip()
            line=line.strip().split()
            if old.startswith("machine"): machine.append(line[-1])
            if old.startswith("login"): login.append(line[-1])
            if old.startswith("password"): password.append(line[-1])
        for i in range(len(machine)):
            try:
               ftp = ftplib.FTP(machine[i])
               ftp.login(login[i],password[i])
            except Exception,e:
                print e
            else:
                ftp.cwd("PublicFolder")
                ftp.storbinary("STOR " + os.path.basename(name), StringIO(content_str), "rb", 8*1024)  
        return name
```

But now it give me the error:

> line:20, in __init__
>   if hasattr(content, 'chunks'):
>   Name error: Global name is not defined.

Can I just write the `_save` method, so it'll work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem has more to do with the format of your code, and not the logic of it. That is, you have some syntax errors.

The error message you included states that the `if hasattr(content, 'chunks'):` line occurs in the `__init__` method, which suggests that the interpreter believes you to be defining the _save method as a function within the **init** method's scope. Your indentation, while not entirely clear here on StackOverflow, seems messy and may be the cause of this confusion. Python is very sensitive to indentation errors.

Comment: The first point is correct, but the second is not. The expression is perfectly valid - look up [generator expressions](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/).

Comment: Interesting, I was somehow unaware of generator expressions. I've edited my answer accordingly.